# How do I shuffle the keypad when typing a PIN?

Tags: security, lock-screens

I just moved to Android from Cyanogen, but I noticed the keypad doesn't shuffle when unlocking the phone. The numbers always show up in the same place, as in a physical phone.

How to I configure Android to shuffle the lock screen keypad?

Comment: Cyanogen? That is a thing from ancient times. Which Android version are you really running?

Comment: Android doesn't provide this feature out of the box, so a possible alternative is to use a 3rd-party lock screen app (if there's any, and working properly)... or custom ROM.